# I Need to provide encryption at rest for a 50GB MySQL instance running on Centos 6.5

Tags: mysql, encryption, centos

I can't use GusterFS because they don't recommend it and Ceph because it's clear they can't guarantee performance.

I can't just encrypt certain database objects because it will take too much engineering

I have lots of disks. I need an effective way of making sure that no-one can get at the data if they do not have access to the platform that uses it.

I'm open to hardware appliances and software solutions. any thoughts?

Comment: Take a look at zncrypt, it's an encrypted filesystem. There is a commercial product named gazzang that is built on zncrypt and provides the user with amongst other features, an ACL to remove access to files without an encryption key.